# How to get values into an array using SnakeYAML

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

Say I have:

```
item:
  field: value
  another: another
```

Is there any way for me to get it in an array as this form:

```
[value, another]
```

Can this be done without much hassle using SnakeYAML in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
item: [value, another]
```

or

```
item:
  - value
  - another
```